# How is data attached in basic pack layout example?

Tags: svg, d3.js

[One of Mike Bostock's relatively simple examples](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063530) of a D3.js pack layout has some features that I find puzzling.  I can't figure out how data gets mapped to other elements.  Can someone explain what's going on?  I'll express my confusion in the form of numbered questions, but many of the questions are closely related.  (It may even be that I have only one simple misunderstanding.)

The example, from the link above:

```
var pack = d3.layout.pack()
    .size([diameter - 4, diameter - 4])
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

// ... define the svg object here

d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {
  var node = svg.datum(root).selectAll(".node")
      .data(pack.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "node" : "leaf node"; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
```

Commentary:

First notice that in the definition of `pack`--the pack layout instance--no data is attached.  This will matter below.

After reading a data file "flare.json", we attach the data (`root`) from the file to the svg object: `svg.datum(root)`.  What does `datum()` do?  It "[sets the element's bound data to the specified value on all selected elements](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#datum)" (without doing a join--i.e. there will be nothing returned by `enter()` or `exit()` if they are called, I guess.

But wait a minute.  No elements have been selected!  What will `root` be attached to?  Or do we say that `svg` is a selection with a single element? [Question 1]

OK, now we `selectAll` instances of the "node" class.  There are none yet, but that's OK; this is a D3 join selection.  It was a little odd to add data before doing the selecting, but OK.

Next we add data to the selection using `data()`: `.data(pack.nodes)`.  OK, that's the normal pattern: Select, then add data.  But wait.  What is in `pack.nodes`?  Remember, we didn't any data to `pack`.  Did we just add no data to an empty selection? [Question 2a]

Or did we add a single data element, which is the `null` (??) that's in `pack.nodes`? [Question 2b]

Apart from, maybe, that `null`, the only data we have in play at this pint is what we added using `svg.datum()`.  Is that playing a role here?  How?  [Question 3]

The next line is the `.enter()` call, which is what usually comes after `.data()`, and it gives us SVG placeholders for every data element that couldn't be matched with an existing SVG element.  But as far as I can tell, we have no SVG elements, and no data elements. Or maybe we have a single data element, the one from `pack.nodes`.  So the `.append("g")` gives us either 0 or 1 `<g></g>`s. Is that correct? But the function used to define the value of "class" for the `g` element seems to assume that there will be more than one `g`.  How can there be multiple `g` elements at this point? [Question 4]

(Thanks for reading this far!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer for your questions is that `pack.nodes` is a [function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pack-Layout#nodes). This function is called with `root` data as an argument.

Q1: `svg` is a selection of a single `<g>` element. See the code:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", diameter)
    .attr("height", diameter)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(2,2)");
```

Q2, Q3: `data(pack.nodes)` is expanded like this:

```
nodes = pack.nodes(svg.datum()) //call the function with the attached data.
data(nodes)
```

These lines will attach an array of `nodes`, for each of them, a `.node` element will be `enter`ed.

Q4: I guess this question should be answered by now.

Let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: Yes that clears it up.  Wonderful.  Many thanks!  I like d3, but sometimes it's difficult to understand the magic.

Comment: About Q1: Would it be more correct to say that `svg` is a selection of `<body>`?  I'm still learning about selections.

Comment: Oh, I see.  `append` returns "[a new selection containing the appended elements.](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#append)"  By the time that the variable `svg` is defined, the result is a selection of a `<g>`.